# Thymeleaf does not Serialize the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I had trying to display a bootstrap modal when i click a row with the extra data 
but when y try to print the object , it does not work:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th># Factura</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Accion</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="bill : ${bills}">
        <td th:text="${bill.bill_id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${bill.client.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${bill.date}"></td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs open-modal" data-whatever="[[{$bill}]]" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#billModal">Ver Detalles</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

so, i dont know how to that bill object and send it to the modal, i have tried many ways.And it only serialize when i put with th:text or th:value

Comment: You want to pass [all values] on a certain `tr element` when a user clicks the button that would open the `#billModal` modal?

Comment: a certain tr, i mean i have bills , but i  want a bill more especific

Comment: Shouldn't you use something like `th:attr="data-whatever=${bill}"`?

Comment: @Phil ok it worked but i dint understand why? why not data-whatever=${bill}"?

Comment: @JustinZuñigaTorres what version of Thymeleaf are you using?

Comment: @Phil I am was using 2.1 but yesterday upgrade to 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
th:attr="data-whatever=${bill}"
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in Thymeleaf 2.x, you need to use the `th:attr` directive to populate arbitrary attribute values (like `data-whatever`).

For example

```
th:attr="data-whatever=${bill}"
```

In Thymeleaf 3, you may be able to use inlined attributes. I haven't used it yet and the documentation does not make it clear if it's safe for attribute values.

See http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-attribute-values

---

According to the docs, you may even be able to use the [default attribute processor](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-the-value-of-any-attribute-default-attribute-processor)

```
th:data-whatever="${bill}"
```